# How to set environment variable for root user at start-up?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to add memory usage monitoring to the monitoring tab of an instance at console.aws.amazon.com. It's an instance running Amazon Linux AMI 2013.09.2 I have found the [Amazon CloudWatch Monitoring Scripts for Linux](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/mon-scripts-perl.html#script_viewmetrics) and specifically mon-put-instance-data.pl that let's me collect memory stats and report it to CloudWatch as custom metrics.

To have this working I need to set the environment variable AWS_CREDENTIAL_FILE to point to a file containing my AWSAccessKeyId and AWSSecretKey. I do this by typing:

```
export AWS_CREDENTIAL_FILE=/home/ec2-user/aws-scripts-mon/awscreds.template
```

To avoid having to type this over and over again, I'm looking for a way to set the environment variable at startup. I have tried adding the code to these files:

```
/etc/rc.local file
/etc/profile
/home/ec2-user/.bash_profile
```

As adding the line of code in either of the files seems to work when I switch to **root user**, where should I put it? If I set the variable in /home/ec2-user/.bash_profile the variable is set for ec2-user but not for root. If i then sudo **-E** su it works, but I don't know if this is the best way to go about it?

Answer (score 6):

Create a sh file and put the code in it. Then put this sh file in **/etc/profile.d/** folder.

**Note:** create this sh file using the root user.

Once your instance is created, this sh file will automatically run and creates the environment variable for you and this environment variable will be accessible to all the users.

Comment: What about if you're trying to add new variables to an existing server?